# How can intercept ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer when I'm using ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE and trying to create a consumer using @KafkaListener at method level in conjunction with ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory. As per my understanding, this would create a ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.

1. Is there an interceptor to intercept this container creation so that I can inject my custom logic to build groupId?
2. If I have two different methods using @KafkaListener to consumer two different topics, would it create two ConcurrentMessageListenerContainers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you have `@KafkaListener(id = "foo", ..., autoStartup = "false")` you can auto wire the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`, and then...

   `registry.getListenerContainer("foo").getContainerProperties().setGroupId(...);` 
   `registry.getListenerContainer("foo").start();`

However, you can simply use

```
@KafkaListener(... groupId "${some.property}")
```

or

```
@KafkaListener(... groupId "#{someSpelExpression}")
```

if all you want to do is set the group id.

2. Yes, a separate container is created for each annotated method.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'll try the first option.

Comment: I've one question here. Do we have this KafkaListenerContainerRegistry in spring-kafka-2.2.7 ?